# Ordered lattice point enumeration

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, lattices, additive-combinatorics

I initially asked this question over at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804095/ordered-lattice-point-enumeration) as it has algorithmic flavor to it, but I haven't been getting much traction so I thought I would probe the mathematics community.

**Setup:** Let $e_{i}$ be an orthogonal (but not orthonormal) basis for $\mathbb{R}^{N}$. Define $\Lambda=\big\{\sum_{j=1}^{N}x_{j}e_{j}\mid x_{j}\in\mathbb{N}\big\}$ (where here I assume $0\in\mathbb{N}$). Now order the points in $\Lambda$ first by their $L^{1}$-norm, breaking ties lexicographically.

**Question:** Is there an efficient algorithm for producing the points in $\Lambda$ in order (up to some pre-defined bound)? Note that I want to walk this set in order, not produce it and then sort it.

**Observations:** This is easy to do if the $e_{i}$ are orthonormal. For instance, the problem is solved [here](https://literateprograms.org/generating_all_integer_lattice_points__python_.html). To make something like this work here, one would need to be able to efficiently answer the following. given positive real numbers $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots, x_{N}$, is there an efficient way to the numbers $\sum_{j=1}^{N}n_{j}x_{j}$ in increasing order, where $n_{j}\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/

Comment: It feels like this is very close to the subset-sum problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: @SteveHuntsman - LattE will only count the points

Comment: @Per Alexandersson It does seem related, but I suspect that the problem I am considering is simpler as negative numbers are explicitly forbidden. Nonetheless, I'll be sure to look closely at subset sum to see if any of the techniques can be adapted.

Comment: @Paul: But you don't need negative numbers, only two subsets with same sum. This seems to be very similar to determining if two elements in $\Lambda$ has the same $L_1$-norm...

Comment: @Per I agree. I was dismayed when I saw NP-complete in the subset sum problem, but I suspect that the problem I'm considering here is not NP-complete.

Comment: We have to be a bit careful using phrases like "NP-complete" here, since, as posed, the problem isn't really in the right form. Would it also be possible to clarify - do you really want an algorithm that uses say O(N) memory beyond the initial data? [Otherwise we're just solving shortest path problems from a single source in the obvious graph, and the usual queue based approaches will be O(1) time per item output.]

Comment: @Michael You're correct, the NP portion of the subset sum problem is asking if there is a subset which sums to zero. I guess the point I was trying to make was that I don't think the problem "Is there a point in $\Lambda$ of given $L^{1}$-norm" is NP-complete. At any rate, it is getting a little off topic. I'm happy to clairify, but I thik I'm a little confused regarding what you're asking. Certainly the problem can be solved by returning paths in the obvious graph of increasing length. I'm likely misunderstanding your point, but I don't see how that is solvable in O(1).

Comment: @Paul What I was trying to say is that we can do this in effectively constant time per item (I think that's correct - may take a bit of work to avoid adding items to the queue on multiple occasions - but it's certainly right if we're treating N as a constant). So if the objective is "list the first 1000 points" that's easily done. If it is "tell me the 1000^th point" then it's less clear.

Comment: @Michael I want to produce the points in order, not jump ahead. So "list the first M points" is what I'm after. Perhaps I'm just being dense, I still don't see what you mean by "usual queue based approaches." Do you have a reference that I could read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to try to answer the version of the Observation which seems to imply that the original "orthogonal" basis condition really is meant to mean "positive multiples of the standard basis vectors". So the problem is, given positive real numbers $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_j$, produce the first $M$ elements of the set $x_1 \mathbb{N} + x_2 \mathbb{N} + \cdots + x_j \mathbb{N}$ in order. For simplicity I'm going to ignore the possibility of ties (this is easily dealt with). The basic idea is just to think of this as a shortest paths problem in the graph $\mathbb{N}^j$ (where the edges are given by the standard basis vectors $e_i$ and the weight of the edge $e_i$ is $n_i$.) Now [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) does this efficiently (we can just stop when the $M$ nearest neighbours are found). For this particular set up there are even some extra gains to be made -- since we know that the distance to a vertex is independent of the path used to get to it, we can choose a standard path to every vertex (e.g., go along the first dimension, then the second, ...) and only add those neighbours that extend such standard paths.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121826/on-the-set-of-numbers-generated-by-integer-linear-combination-of-two-real-number/121883#121883) seems related to the case $N=2.$ I gave an answer suggesting that the continued fraction expansion of ${|e_2|}/{|e_1|}$ was the key. I haven't rechecked it.
I'd venture that already the case $N=3$ would be much more difficult.